# Fail a build on assembly reference conflicts

Tags: .net, msbuild

I am trying to force a build to fail if any assembly conflicts are detected.

The default MSBuild script runs a task called ResolveAssemblyReference to locate all dependencies and attempt to resolve any conflicts.  However, it will favour primary references and higher version assemblies and depending on various rules inside the ResolveAssemblyReference task, it will will either choose the higher version assembly or worse, arbitrarily choose the conflict winner.

There are problems with this approach; in certain situations the build will pass happily and but fail at runtime.
e.g.

App->Assemby1->Assembly3 V1

App->Assembly2->Assembly3 V1.1

In some cases depending on strong names and rules inside ResolveAssemblyReference, Assembly3V1 might be chosen as the conflict winner and so a runtime error can be generated if Assembly2 depends on a new method or class in version 1.1 of Assembly3. (there are a lot of variations that can also cause a successful build and runtime failure)

We are moving away from project references and starting to use NuGet for internal component management and as such, this problem becomes a bigger issue for us.  I'd like to modify our default MSBuild script to fail the build when any conflicts are detected (with the ability to override/ignore vetted conflicts).

The problem is that while the ResolveAssemblyReference task does a thorough job of identifying conflicts, it will only generate a warning in the particular case when the reference that looses a conflict is a primary reference.  For all other conflicts, it simply logs a message to the build output.

I am looking for a way to generate a warning or error if a conflict is detected so the build will fail.

Ideas?

Comment: Editing the MSBuild .targets files invokes another kind of DLL Hell.  Build Hell is nothing to mess with.

Comment: @eamon: did you find a solution?